# How to redirect from one page to another page in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, redirect, post

I have a page for registration i.e (Registration.php) that file contains form variables such as `firstname`, `lastname`, `adress`, `username` and `password`.

I need to encrypt the username and password and write it to a file. To do that I am posting the form to another page which is called saveRegistration.php, where I am encrypting the username and password and then finally write it to a file.

Now on successful completion of these operations, I have to redirect the user to another page, where I would display the success message of successful login. How do I accomplish this?

The saveRegistration.php does only contain some PHP and no forms. I am also writing i.e. echoing messages.

How do I post from this page to another page to display the message?

Comment: Here are some newlines: `\n\n\n\n\n`. Please take them and use to make your text more readable

Comment: Have you consulted Google? http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=php+redirect&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Answer (score 4):

This is quite simple. What you need to do is create a new page, you can call it whatever you like, but for the sake of it let's call it

`register_success.php` Now in this file just put the message you would like the user too see.

In order to redirect the user from `saveRegistration.php` file you need to use the `header()` function.

So your `saveRegistration.php` file would look like something like this:

```
<?php

//Your current code... Insert the user in to the database...

//When that is done, we make a redirect

header("Location: register_success.php");
exit;

?>
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you get a `headers already sent` error when you try this, you'll need to make sure that the php script isn't outputting anything to the page before the `header` line. i.e. no `echo` statements or blank lines that aren't enclosed by `<?php` and `?>` tags etc. It's unlikely you'll be doing that anyway, but just in case :)

Answer (score 2):

```
header("Location:PAGE-NAME-OR-PATH");
```